# How can I send a folder as response to the client via REST using Java?

Tags: java, file, rest, response, httpresponse

I want to send a folder or list of  files in the particular folder as response to the client  via REST using java. My server side is EJB.

I am trying with following code. But got FileNotFoundException

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFiles() {
    File file = new File("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\MyFolder");
    return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
}
```

Tried with the following code. But got NullPointerException

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFiles() {
    File file = new File("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\MyFolder");
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(file.listFiles());
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=units.zip");
    return response.build();
}
```

Working in a windows machine.

Can anyone give me any advice, or examples of working code to conform to?

Comment: Since nothing is found from `"/path of the folder"`, maybe you could add the actual string you used into the question?

Comment: On my phone, but you need `getResource` for files packaged inside your app.

Comment: @t0mppa: Please find the updated question

Comment: You'll have to zip your folder explicitely. JAX-RS won't create a zip file for you. Look at the java.util.zip package.

Comment: @JBNizet: I just taken that example for the internet. But actually I don't want to zip my folder and send to client. What I want is I need the same folder/files in the folder in the client

Comment: You can't send a folder. That's not possible. Try to remember the last time you downloaded a folder from a web site. You have never done that, because it's simply not possible. You can download files. And those files can be zipped files. But you can't download a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Either use forward slashes or double backslashes in the file name.

Also, don't expect the folder to be zipped automagically. You'll have to create the ZIP archive and pass it to the `Response`.

Comment: I just taken that example for the internet. But actually I don't want to zip my folder and send to client. What I want is I need the same folder/files in the folder in the client